# Why do I need to add a class two times to make justify work?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why my menu-items only correctly show when the class menu is added to the direct parent and then again to the parent of the parent.

When I remove one of the to menu classes the span items won't justify.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLVwJV

```
<nav>
<div class="top-nav"></div>
<div class="bottom-nav">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h1>Portfolio van Dirk</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 menu">
            <div class="menu">
                <span>Concepten</span>
                <span>Ontwerp</span>
                <span>Artikelen </span>
                <span>Programmeren</span>
                <span>curriculum vitea</span>
                <span>Contact</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.menu
text-align: justify
text-transform: lowercase
position: relative
padding-top: 20px

span
    padding-bottom: 20px
    font-weight: 200
    font-size: 18px
    color: white 

.menu:after
    content: ' '
    display: inline-block
    width: 100%
    height: 0 

.menu > span 
    display: inline-block
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Sass CSS you defined a .menu class within a .menu class. So your css is  compiling to:

```
.menu .menu > span {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu .menu:after {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}
```

That's not what you want. So remove "menu" from your column `div` so that it looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

and update your sass css so it looks like this:

```
.menu
    text-align: justify
    text-transform: lowercase
    position: relative
    padding-top: 20px

    span
        padding-bottom: 20px
        font-weight: 200
        font-size: 18px
        color: white 

    &:after
        content: ' '
        display: inline-block
        width: 100%
        height: 0 

    > span 
        display: inline-block
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/BjqegN

Answer (score 2):

Look at Your compiled css, remove some spaces, and here You go.

```
.menu .menu:after {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
.menu .menu > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWeodM

Answer (score 1):

That's not because of your `menu` class `justify` rule. It's other rules that cause the menu to collapse.

I've removed `justify` from the `.menu` class styles, and added a new `just` class with just the `justify`! 
And it works when only givven to the inner `div`, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGgEjg